How can I redirect the first user in next-auth and store the session information?
I implemented Google OAuth login using next-auth. In the async signIn function, I query the database with the getUser function, and if it is the first time the user logs in, I redirect them to the /sign-up page. However, on the /sign-up page, I found that the session was null. I considered using an adapter, but it would create many tables in the database. I want to minimize the values stored in the database.
// auth.ts
export const { handlers, auth } = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ user, account, profile }) {
      if (account?.provider === "google") {
        const isNewUSer = await getUser({ uuid: profile.sub });

        if (!isNewUSer) {
          return true;
        }
      }
      return "/sign-up";
    },
    async jwt({ token, account, profile }) {
      if (account && profile) {
        token.sub = profile.sub;
        token.name = profile.name;
        token.email = profile.email;
        token.isNewUser = false;
      }

      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      if (session.user) {
        session.user.id = token.sub;
        session.user.isNewUser = token.isNewUser as boolean;
      }
      return session;
    },
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
    newUser: "/sign-up",
  },
});


// /sign-up/page.tsx
import { auth } from "@/auth";

export default async function SignUp() {
  const session = await auth();
  console.log("sign-up session = ", session); // looged with google, but session is null
  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        {/* "The action stores user information such as nickname, uuid, and email in the database.  */}
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your Nickname" name="nickname" />
        <button>Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}


How can I redirect a new user to the /sign-up page while passing the user information received from Google?
next-router:app-router
next:14.2.16
next-auth:5.0.0 (beta)

in you auth.ts you can use this, to modify the signIn callback to return true for successful sign-ins and manage redirection on the client-side:
export const { handlers, auth } = NextAuth({
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET as string,
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ user, account, profile }) {
      if (account?.provider === "google") {
        const isNewUser = await getUser({ uuid: profile.sub });
        
        if (isNewUser) {
          // in here you can store user information in the token and allow for redirection later
          return true; // This will allow session creation
        }
      }
      return true; // If not a new user, proceed with the normal flow
    },
    async jwt({ token, account, profile }) {
      if (account && profile) {
        token.sub = profile.sub;
        token.name = profile.name;
        token.email = profile.email;
        token.isNewUser = true;  // Mark as new user if necessary
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      if (session.user) {
        session.user.id = token.sub;
        session.user.isNewUser = token.isNewUser;
      }
      return session;
    },
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
    newUser: "/sign-up", // sign-up page if it's a new user
  },
});

and then in /sign-up/page.tsx, you can use useSession hook
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

export default function SignUp() {
  const { data: session, status } = useSession();
  const router = useRouter();

  // Redirect to login page if no session exists
  if (status === "loading") {
    return <div>Loading</div>;
  }

  if (!session) {
    router.push("/login");
    return null;
  }

  // Check if it iss a new user and show sign-up form accordingly
  if (session.user.isNewUser) {
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your Nickname" name="nickname" />
          <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }

  // If the user is not new, you can show a different page or message
  return <page_link or message>;
}


There are two things you can do

Ensure the signIn Callback Redirects Correctly: Modify the signIn callback to handle the redirection correctly after the user is authenticated.

Use useSession Hook on the /sign-up Page: Use useSession on the /sign-up page to retrieve the session, which will allow you to access the user data and manage the flow without relying on query parameters or manual session handling.


Explanation:

SignIn Callback:

If it's a new user, the signIn callback will redirect them to /sign-up after checking the database.
When returning true in the signIn callback for a new user, NextAuth automatically handles the session.

Session Handling:

The jwt callback adds user data to the token (e.g., name, email, sub for user ID).
The session callback adds that data to the session, which is accessible in the client-side useSession hook.

useSession on /sign-up:

When the user is redirected to the /sign-up page, useSession is used to fetch the session data and access user details (such as their name and email).
If the session is still loading, the page will show a loading state.
If the session is not available (e.g., user manually navigates to /sign-up without being authenticated), you can redirect them to the login page (router.push("/login")).

Thank you. However, there are a few things I don't understand. Firstly, for next-auth to store information in the session, the signIn callback must return true. However, when the user is new (isNewUser === true), I am trying to redirect them using return '/sign-up'. How can I attempt to redirect while also storing the information in the session?

I have posted a new answer, this might be helpful to you.
